# Magento2: How to add a confirmation message after a message is sent via Contact Us?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

we have a Contact Us form that is used for customer to enter questions/comments.  Although the email is sent out there is no confirmation page that says something like  "Your message has been sent". Is there anyway to add this?

thanks! 
Ahdee

Answer (score 1):

[Check there has any message object like this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L73).

If not then added in your controller after sending message.

**For success:**

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(
    __('Your message has been sent')
);
```

**For error:**

```
$this->messageManager->addError(
    __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
);
```

Comment: thank you. However, where can I find this controller file? I'm using the default contact us page I believe.

Comment: Actually, I located the file, ..vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php; its probably bad form to edit Magento's core files but I don't know how to redirect this.  I found the addSuccess part however, strangely it is there; its just not showing up.  So what I ended up doing was redirecting to a cms page and not only did it work but the green message field showed up this time.  This was my one line of code a modified to, ```$this->_redirect('contactus');```

Comment: It's missing part in your theme. There must be missing message container.